# dataType vs accepts - Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to understand the difference between accepts and dataType in a Ajax Request.  Documentation states:

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

accepts (default: depends on DataType)
Type: PlainObject
The content type sent in the request header that tells the server what kind of response it will accept in return.

dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
Type: String
The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

Basically, Is it the same?, it has the same purpose.

Comment: "You send" vs "You're expecting"

Comment: To send is contentType, my question is about dataType and accepts both of them are apparently for what i am expecting from the server.

Comment: It looks like `accepts` is the way you have to tell the server what type of answer do you want, in case it has many options to offer, while `dataType` is what you are expecting as a response so the response is corectly parsed.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. Let's see if a more precise answer come out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a, hopefully, precise answer:

**The `accepts` option let you change the `Accept` header in the request**

When you change this option, the `Accept` header in the request will be set to the one(s) specified. Take notice that it is not a string, but an object mapping the MIME type of the accepted responses. Like `{ text: "text/plain", html: "text/html" }`. The `Accept` header can be used by the server to provide the response in the format expected by the request, or fail in case it can't provide the response in one of the formats expected by the request.

A really important thing is that, at least in jQuery 1.11.3 (where I tested), this options seems to not be working, instead I managed to change the header using the `headers` option: `headers: {Accept : "text/json"}`.

**The `dataType` option let you pre-process the response**

If you define a `dataType`, the response of the request will be pre-processed by jQuery before being available to the succes handler. For example:

> If `json` is specified, the response is parsed using `jQuery.parseJSON` before being passed, as an object, to the success handler.
>
> If `script` is specified, `$.ajax()` will execute the JavaScript that is received from the server before passing it on to the success handler as a string.

More examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), in the "Data Types" section.

In case that `dataType` is not set, the `Content-Type` of the response will determine what pre-processing should be done to the response. Be aware that changing the `dataType` will change the `Accept` header too. Usually there is no need to change the `Accept` header by yourself.

**Example**

*request.php*

```
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"],"text/javascript") === false)
    exit("I only provide text/javascript responses");

echo "alert('This is my response!')";
```

*index.html*

```
<button id="send">Send</button>
<div id="response"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    
    $("#send").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "request.php",
            dataType: "script" // Change this to "text" and you will see the difference
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("#response").text(data);
        });
    });
    
    
});
</script>
```

When the `dataType` is set to `"script"` the `Accept` header will include `"text/javascript"` so the test on `request.php` will pass. It will return `"alert('This is my response!')"` and because the `dataType` is set to `"script"` jQuery will attempt to execute that as javascript and then pass it as plain text to the success handler.

If you change the `dataType` to `"text"` the `Accept` header will NOT include `"text/javascript"` so the test on `request.php` will fail. It will return `"I only provide text/javascript responses"` and because the `dataType` is set to `"text"` jQuery will pass it as plain text to the success handler.

Comment: I was having issues with accept headers also on 1.11.2, using `headers: {Accept : "application/json"}`made it work. For some reason it was sending  `Accept: */*` even though contentType and dateType etc were all set for json.