# Using jquery in ajax request to get javascript response UJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In Rails, you can respond to different MIME types, including `application/javascript`. You often use this MIME type for ajax requests to send javascript back to the browser to be evaluated. The `respond_to` symbol is `:js`.

I see examples like this:

```
<%= form_tag('/articles', remote: true) do %>
  ...
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Delete article", @article, remote: true, method: :delete %>
```

The rails.js file finds the remote links, forms, and inputs, and overrides their click events to submit to the server via AJAX.

Server has something like this:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
```

In my situation, I need to do the request in jQuery, so I cannot use the remote: true feature.

```
<%= form_for @tag do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :taggings, f.object.taggings.build do |taggings_builder| %>
    <%= taggings_builder.hidden_field :tagging_flag, value: @contact.flag %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Add a tag and press enter' %>
<% end %>
```

My problem is when I specify `contentType` as `'application/javascript'` in jquery `ajax` method, no form data is sent to server. I even inspected it in Network tab on chrome.
When I remove the `contentType` property, the form data is submitted to server but the the content type is not '`application/javascript`'. It is '`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`'.

My jquery looks like this:

```
$view.on('keypress','form#add-tag input#tag_name', function(e){
   var $form = $(this).closest('form');
   var key = e.which;

   if(key == 13){

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: $form.serialize(),
         contentType: 'application/javascript',
         url: $form.attr('action'),
         beforeSend: function() {
           $('.loading').show();
         },
         complete: function(){
           $('.loading').hide();
         },
         success: function(resp){
         }
      });


     return false;
   }
})
```

How can I send the form data to server with the content type of 'application/javascript'?

Comment: Ok, it seems by removing contentType: 'application/javascript', from the ajax call, it sends 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' instead of 'application/javascript', and even though the mime type is not 'application/javascript', it still responds to the :js mime type in the controller. Why does it still respond to the :js mime type in the controller?

Comment: `contentType` is the type of the parameters being sent to the controller, not the type of response expected.

Comment: @Donato Why u cannot use `remote true` ? I am little curious ))) It does the same thing actually.

Comment: @7urkm3n because the form does not have a submit button. User must press the enter key for form to be submitted. Plus I have a little spinner when user press enter key. Can this stuff be done while still using remote true? If so, show me as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: You could have the javascript listen for the enter key and trigger the form submit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060712/datatype-vs-accepts-ajax-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contentType` option is used to specify the format of the parameters being sent to the controller. To specify the type of data expected in response, use the `dataType` option; specifying `script` means you expect Javascript, and this will send the `Accept: application/javascript` header that tells the controller which `respond_to` block should be used.

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: $form.serialize(),
     dataType: 'script',
     url: $form.attr('action'),
     beforeSend: function() {
       $('.loading').show();
     },
     complete: function(){
       $('.loading').hide();
     },
     success: function(resp){
     }
  });
```